# How can I most quickly edit the text highlighted by incremental search?

Tags: emacs

Given such text

> Hello, World

I do incremental search for "world"

> C-s World

The text is highlihted

> Hello, **World**

Now I would like to type new text "All" instead of the highlighted and get:

> Hello, All

How can I do this? (Notice, I am NOT looking for "query-replace", or alike). Ideally it have to be some thing like this:

> C-s World BS All

Comment: Needs more upvotes, this has been driving me crazy.  Seems like it should be a built-in.  I mean, we have M-x butterfly but not this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can't use <kbd>backspace</kbd> because that key is required to modify your query.

I have this in my init:

```
(defun le::isearch-kill-result ()
  (interactive)
  (if (use-region-p)
      (call-interactively 'kill-region)
    (kill-region (point) isearch-other-end))
  (isearch-exit))
(define-key isearch-mode-map [(control w)] 'le::isearch-kill-result)
```

My point is never at anything useful when I search, so I don't mind overriding
<kbd>C-w</kbd>, you may want to pick another key.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no official way to do exactly what you want to. The closest way will be "`C-s World M-% All`" if `isearch-query-replace` does not belong to the `query-replace` relatives by your definition.

> `(isearch-query-replace &optional DELIMITED REGEXP-FLAG)`
>
> Start `query-replace` with string to replace from last search string.

Answer (score 1):

This was bugging me as well, and so here is what I eventually came up with.

### Quick Setup

First you'll need [Isearch+](http://www.emacswiki.org/IsearchPlus).
If you are in Emacs 24 or later (or otherwise have ELMA/package.el) you can get Isearch+ with

```
M-x package-install <RET> isearch+ <RET>
```

Then add this line to your `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") 'isearchp-set-region-around-search-target)
```

Then with your cursor at the end, `C-x C-e` to make this change in the current session.
(This uses `C-.`, you can change this to whatever keys you want instead.)

### How To Use

```
C-s World C-. C-w All
```

### How it works

It is selecting (in proper Emacs parlance, it sets the *active region*) the highlighted text, then `C-w` is killing that text (putting it in the kill ring).  The string `World` can now be pasted later if you want with `C-y`.

### If the word is long

There are some other goodies in isearch+.  For example, If "World" was a longer word,  like "Worcestershire", and you didn't want to type it all, you could try this:

```
C-s W C-( C-. C-w All
```

With isearch+, `C-(` will yank the rest of the word in the current "search target" into your search, so in this case it'd add `orchestershire` to the current i-search for you.